# How to change android:configChanges programmatically?

Tags: android

How to change android confgurations : `configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"` programmatically?

I mean can we change this options during run-time?

Comment: Why you want to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

you can not. What you can do, for instace, is to fix the screen orientation